# Google PHP API returning invalid argument error

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to get location insights through the Google PHP Library.
I am doing the example for -> Retrieving basic insights for a given list of locations.
from this page: https://support.google.com/business/thread/1774669/php-code-example-insights-with-mybusiness-php-v3-2?hl=en

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/google/auth_google.php";
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/MyBusiness.php";

$mybusinessService = new Google_Service_Mybusiness($client);
$accounts = $mybusinessService->accounts;
$accountsList = $accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
$locationStatistics = [];
//
foreach ($accountsList as $accKey => $account) {

    $locations = $mybusinessService->accounts_locations;
    $locationsList = $locations->listAccountsLocations($account->name)->getLocations();



//
    $firstDay = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z", strtotime(date('Y-m-1')));
    $lastDay = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z", strtotime("today"));

//    // Final Goal of my Code
    if (empty($locationsList)===false) {
        foreach ($locationsList as $locKey => $location) {
            $reviewLink = $location['metadata']['newReviewUrl'];
            $locationNames =  $location->locationName;

            $reportLocationInsightsRequest = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_ReportLocationInsightsRequest($client);
            $basicRequest = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_BasicMetricsRequest($client);
            $metricRequests = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_MetricRequest($client);
            $metricRequests->setMetric("ALL");
            $basicRequest->setMetricRequests($metricRequests);
            $timeRange = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_TimeRange($client);
            $timeRange->setStartTime($firstDay);
            $timeRange->setEndTime($lastDay);
            $basicRequest->setTimeRange($timeRange);
            $reportLocationInsightsRequest->setBasicRequest($basicRequest);
            $reportLocationInsightsRequest->setLocationNames(array($location->name));
            $reportLocationInsightsResponse = $locations->reportInsights($account->name, $reportLocationInsightsRequest);
            $locationMetrics = $reportLocationInsightsResponse->getLocationMetrics();
            $locationMetricsArray = array();
            $locationMetricsArray['locationMetrics']['locationName'] = array($locationMetrics[0]->getLocationName());
            $locationMetricsArray['locationMetrics']['timeZone'] = array($locationMetrics[0]->getTimeZone());
            $metricValuesArray = array();
            foreach ($locationMetrics[0]->getMetricValues() as $value) {
                $metricValuesItem = array();
                $metricValuesItem['metric'] = $value['metric'];
                $metricValuesItem['totalValue']['timeDimension']['timeRange']['endTime'] = $value['totalValue']['timeDimension']['timeRange']['endTime'];
                $metricValuesItem['totalValue']['timeDimension']['timeRange']['startTime'] = $value['totalValue']['timeDimension']['timeRange']['startTime'];
                $metricValuesItem['totalValue']['metricOption'] = $value['totalValue']['metricOption'];
                $metricValuesItem['totalValue']['value'] = $value['totalValue']['value'];
                $metricValuesArray[] = $metricValuesItem;
            }

            $locationMetricsArray['locationMetrics']['metricValues'] = $metricValuesArray ;
            $locData =array();
            $locID = str_replace('https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=', '', $reviewLink);
            $locData['name'] = $locationNames;
            $locData['reviewLink'] = $reviewLink;
            $locData['locationID'] = $locID;
}
}
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the code. The problem was happening from the

```
$firstDay = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z", strtotime(date('Y-m-1')));
$lastDay = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z", strtotime("today"));
```

If $firstDay and $lastDay are equal the API returns an error.